# Question about integration by parts for quotiens

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I have a quotient $f(x)/g(x)$ well defined on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $f(0)/g(0)$. Suppose they are both differentiable functions and $f(x)/g(x)$ is continuous.

In such a situation ($1/g(x)$ by itself is not well defined on all of $[-1,1]$, even though $f$ and $f/g$ are)can one apply integration by parts? as in does this hold?
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x)^{-1} dx = \frac{F(1)}{g(1)} -   \frac{F(-1)}{g(-1)}
+ \int_{-1}^1  \frac{F(x)}{g(x)^2}g'(x) dx
$$
here $F(x) = \int_{-1}^x f(t) dt$.
Thank you!

(Alternatively, my question is under what conditions can one apply integration by parts to quotients of functions)

Edit. Error has been corrected based on a solution below

Comment: "$f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $f(0)/g(0)$ is well defined." These statements are contradictory. Do you mean the limit of $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x \to 0$ for the latter?

Comment: how about for example $f(t) = g(t) = t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differentiation rule for quotients is $$\left(\frac{F(x)}{g(x)}\right)' = \frac{F'(x)g(x)-F(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}.$$

By rearranging the terms (we solve for the first term on the right hand side), this becomes $$\frac{F'(x)}{g(x)} = \left(\frac{F(x)}{g(x)}\right)' + \frac{F(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}.$$

Integration of this equation from $-1$ to $1$ yields $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{F'(x)}{g(x)}dx = \frac{F(1)}{g(1)} - \frac{F(-1)}{g(-1)} + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{F(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}dx.$$

This is analogous to integration by parts for products. We could have also derived this equation from the usual [integration by parts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) by noting that $\left(\frac{1}{g(x)}\right)'=-\frac{g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$.

Now we can set $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf(t)dt$ and obtain the correct version of your formula: $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx = \frac{F(1)}{g(1)} - \frac{F(-1)}{g(-1)} + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{F(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}dx.$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in the statement. I added some corrections. I'm wondering does it matter if for example at $x=0$, $1/g(x)$ is not well defined? (but $f(x)/g(x)$ is well defined and also $\int_{-1}^1f(x)/g(x) dx$ exists)

Comment: @JohnnyT. It does not matter. The only thing that matters is that all expressions and integrals in the equation are well-defined.